# Can an SQL query contain logic dependant on other rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to discover rows that are inserted out of order in a table where the primary key is an autoincremented and non-reused row ID.  I was wondering if it is possible to construct a query in SQL that is based off other rows in the query, i.e.

```
Select *
From table
Where InsertTime < previous row's InsertTime
Order by RowID
```

That would roughly do what I want, but to my limited SQL knowledge it's not possible and instead I would have to run the remainder of the query and do that test manually when iterating over the rows.  Is that correct?

This is in an SQLite database if it makes a difference.

Comment: How would you define a "previous row"? Based on the row id?

Comment: Yes, based off the row id.

Answer (score 1):

You can get values from the previous row with a correlated subquery, where "previous row" means the row with the next smaller rowid, where "next smaller" is implemented as "the largest rowid that is smaller":

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE InsertTime < (SELECT InsertTime
                    FROM MyTable AS T2
                    WHERE T2.rowid < MyTable.rowid
                    ORDER BY rowid DESC
                    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY rowid
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQLite does not support CTE's, or window functions which make this sort of thing easy.  If your order is based on your RowID you can get a row number with a correlated subquery, do this twice and then join the results together offsetting the row number by 1:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
      SELECT Rowid, dt, (SELECT COUNT(rowid) 
                         FROM table1 b  
                         WHERE a.rowid >= b.rowid) as RN
      FROM table1 a
      )t1
JOIN  (SELECT Rowid, dt, (SELECT COUNT(rowid) 
                         FROM table1 b  
                         WHERE a.rowid >= b.rowid) as RN
       FROM table1 a
       )t2
 ON t1.RN = t2.RN +1
WHERE t1.dt < t2.dt
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/79bb5/5/1)